# regex to parse out data from text

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using Ruby 2.2 to parse the following text:

```
[key1: this is a bunch of text that can 
span multiple lines. 
key2: foo 
key2: bar
key3: this can span multiple lines 
as well 
]
```

Into an array of hashes that look like this:

```
[
    key1: "this is a bunch of text that can span multiple lines."
    key2: ["foo", "bar"]
    key3: "this can span multiple lines as well"
]
```

My first goal is to come up with the regex to parse out the key/value pairs and this is what I am stuck on:

```
/\[((key1|key2|key3): (.+?))+(?=(?:key1:|key2:|key3:|\]))/m
```

It's not working because the lookahead I'm using to look for the next key or closing bracket seems to be matching text. My understanding is that it doesn't.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: One thing to change is make the second group around the keys non capturing: `\[((key1|key2|key3): (.+?))(?=(?:key1:|key2:|key3:|\]))`

Comment: @jacob.m doh! good catch.

Comment: No problem! And if you could probably also make the outer group non-capturing (unless you need "key: whatever text" [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/5bMBGpHsoX) `\[(?:(key1|key2|key3): (.+?))(?=(?:key1:|key2:|key3:|\]))`

Comment: @jacob.m Thanks. I'll keep that in mind for the final version. I'll keep it out for now because that regex is looking pretty hairy (to me at least).

Comment: Sounds good, but either way rubular is a good website for testing regexp :)

Comment: While [this](https://regex101.com/r/oQ2yI0/1) is rather ugly and doesn't combine both `key2` into a single key, nor does it handle keys that contain double quotes with the possibility of `[` and `]` characters, it DOES hit much of the OP's requirements. :-)

Comment: Are you interested by something like this? http://rubular.com/r/LWZTiy8yUz

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thank you! It seems to do the job. I just need to digest it!

Comment: @AllenLiu: be careful, I assumed that the closing bracket has its own line. but with a little change: http://rubular.com/r/5YtcclhgJJ

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Ok. Thanks for the heads up. It actually doesn't need to be but maybe that'll be an exercise for me to try to work with this regex. BTW, you should post it as answer so I can credit you.

Comment: What you have is not a valid object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = %Q|[key1: this is a bunch of text that can 
span multiple lines. 
key2: foo 
key2: bar
key3: this can span multiple lines 
as well 
]|

p data[1..-2] #Remove square brackets [...] 
  .split(/(key\d):\s+/)[1..-1] #regexp out keys and values. (And get rid of initial empty string)
  .each_slice(2) #Group into key-value lists
  .group_by(&:shift) # Group by first values
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution. Thanks!